# Trying to set a SharedPreference using the ON_BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I am having an enormous amount of difficulty in setting a SharedPreference every time the user's device is rebooted.

I posted this question a few days ago and received two answers, both of which regarded errors in my code which I have corrected, however, the problem persists.

Any help would be supremely appreciated.

Here's my code:

**MyReceiver.java**

```
       package ***************;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String TAG ="MyReceiver";
        Log.d(TAG,"Did I Run?" );

        mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();

        edit.putString("status", "Masqed Crusader is OFFLINE");
         edit.commit();
      }

}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:versionCode="1" package="*********" android:versionName="1.8.3">
                  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity android:name=".Main"
                          android:label="@string/app_name"
                          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"                                 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                         <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <activity android:name="help"></activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">

                <intent-filter> 
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE"/> 

                </intent-filter> 
  </receiver>
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

The SharedPreferences are setup in my Main activity. My goal is to get the ON_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast to trigger the MyReceiver activity, which resets a specific sharedPreference, however, when I try this, the SharedPref is not reset.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your application installed onto the SD card? If you put a log line in your onReceive method, is the line logged?

Comment: @David The app is not installed on the SD card. I just added a log line to my code and to the original post... the line does not appear to be logged, although i will admit that I could be doing something wrong.

Comment: Good stuff - I ask because the SD card is mounted after BOOT_COMPLETED but obviously not a problem here.

Comment: @David Thanks for the input... did i implement the log line correctly?

Comment: Yeah, you should be seeing log lines. advantej's suggestion below looks promising!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might sound stupid, but try removing the android.intent.category.DEFAULT line. This is the only difference I can see in one of my apps which is working !

Comment: thanks for the input, i removed that line in both my code and the original post... unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, should't it be android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED ? I see that the last 'D' is missing in your intent filter !

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!! I cannot believe I didn't catch that typo sooner... I have been working on this for three days now, haha Thanks Again!!

Comment: Ha ha ! It does happen :) I know its frustrating.

Comment: These errors are usually avoided in Java as constants are checked...but in XML it is just a string. Very frustrating.

Comment: THIS!!!!! This answer should have a lot of upvotes! Here is the only plase where it is, or at least, where i found it, and it's a horrible error... TY!!! (Sorry for the comment in an old post, but i have to do this)